# Perl Path::Class::file with "use constant" gives blessed ref, not string - why?

Tags: perl, constants

Running Perl 5.18 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I wanted to create some pathname constants so I did

```
use Path::Class;
use constant FILEPATH => file('directory', 'filename');
```

However, when I came to use the constant in a hash aggregate ...

```
my $hash = { filepath => FILEPATH };
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $href;
```

... I was surprised to discover that the value of the `filepath` key was a blessed reference, not the string result from the function call that I was expecting.

I can work around the problem like this ...

```
use constant FILEPATH => file('directory', 'filename') . "";
```

... which forces the Perl interpreter to evaluate the blessed reference, but

(a) is there a better way, and
(b) what the heck is going on?!

I know that `use constant` is evaluated in a list context, but normally `use constant MYCONST => mysub(arg1, arg2);` does The Right Thing, evaluates the subroutine call and uses the return value. What's the cleverness with `Path::Class::file` that breaks this expectation?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with `use constant` - it's the hash initialiser that causes it - `my $href = { filepath => file('directory', 'filename') };` also assigns the blessed ref to the key.

Comment: Nothing to do with hash initialisers either! `my $scalar = file('directory', 'filename'); print Dumper $scalar;` does it too!

Comment: In case you're wondering, the actual use case with the constant is in conjunction with `HTML::Tiny`.  I'm doing `print $h->form({action=>URL})` where `URL` is the constant, and I get an empty `action` attribute in the HTML, presumably because HTML::Tiny is choking on the non-string value for the `action` key.

Comment: It turns out that `HTML::Tiny` was the culprit - there's a bug in the `{ attr => [] }` processing that inserts a valueless attribute - it takes anything for which `ref` returns TRUE to trigger this behaviour, so objects are ignored.  See my answer.

Comment: To summarise another answer thread, my initial error in diagnosing this problem was thinking that `Path::Class::file` returns a string. It doesn't, it returns a `Path::Class::File` object as @ikegami pointed out, and an object in Perl is a `ref`, which triggered the "valueless attribute" behaviour. There's been some discussion about whether this should happen for a ref that isn't a reference to an empty array which I won't repeat here.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question got a downvote as others may well make the same mistake with constants and self-stringifying objects as me. If you downvoted, please have the courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right about Path::Class::file returning an object.  That's what all the "bless" stuff was in the Dumper output.  Sorry I didn't realise that sooner.

As you'll see from my comments, I ran into the problem using `HTML::Tiny`, which you can see as follows:-

```
$ perl -MPath::Class -MHTML::Tiny -le 'print HTML::Tiny->new(mode=>"html")->form({action=>file("cgi-bin", "script")})'
<form action></form>
```

As you can see, the `action` attribute is missing the path.  However,

```
$ perl -MPath::Class -MHTML::Tiny -le 'print HTML::Tiny->new(mode=>"html")->form({action=>file("cgi", "script").""})'
<form action="cgi/script"></form>
```

This works because the `.""` string concatenation operator causes the Class::Path::File object's automatic stringifier to be called, so an actual string is passed in the `{action=>value}` hash, not an object.

If you dig into the [HTML::Tiny 1.05](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tiny/lib/HTML/Tiny.pm) code, you'll find `sub _tag` on line 622, which goes

```
if ( ref $val ) {
    return $attr if not $self->_xml_mode;
```

This test allows you to use `{ attr=>[] }` to output an attribute name without a value, but unfortunately the test is also TRUE if `$val` is an object.  I'll raise a bug report for this against HTML::Tiny.

Comment: Seems that I'm not the first person to run into this - https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=81682 was opened 5 years ago - I guess I'll be using the `stringify` workaround!

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated. And common courtesy.

Comment: As to whether a self-stringifying object is a valid scalar input value for HTML::Tiny, it's straightforward to investigate: `perl -MHTML::Tiny -MPath::Class -le 'use constant MYPATH => file("directory","filename"); print HTML::Tiny->new(mode=>"html")->tag("p", "mypath", "=", MYPATH, [ MYPATH, "=", "mypath" ], [ \"b", "mypath", "=", MYPATH ], { mypath=>MYPATH }, MYPATH )'` gives `<p>mypath</p><p>=</p><p>directory/filename</p><p>directory/filename=mypath</p><p><b>mypath</b><b>=</b><b>directory/filename</b></p><p mypath>directory/filename</p>` so it stringified correctly except in the href case.

Answer (score 5):

The [`file` function from the module Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class#file) is in fact a constructor for a Path::Class object. It always returns an object. Even the [SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class#SYNOPSIS) says so.

> ```
> use Path::Class;
>
> my $dir  = dir('foo', 'bar');       # Path::Class::Dir object
> my $file = file('bob', 'file.txt'); # Path::Class::File object
> ```

If all you want is the path, call that method on the return value of `file` and assign that calls' return value to your constant. The object you get is a [Path::Class::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::File). It provides various methods. To do the same as when you use the string overload, call the `stringify` method.

```
use constant FILEPATH => file('directory', 'filename')->stringify;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Unfortunately `HTML::Tiny` uses `ref $val` to check whether `$val` is a scalar (string) and ignores it if it isn't - see my answer for details.

Comment: And, yes, taking the time to RTFM and get the function you're calling to return a string if that's what you want in your constant is sound advice.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant part of HTML::Tiny decides what to do based on the type of the inputs. It expects either `undef`, a string or an array ref, but you provided something that is none of these. In other words, this is a case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). You are using the value returned by `file()`, which is an object that overloads stringification.

Use either of the following to provide the expected input:

```
 use constant FILEPATH => file('directory', 'filename')->stringify;
```

or

```
 use constant FILEPATH => "".file('directory', 'filename');
```

Note that it's usually unsafe to unsafe to use objects as constants because they're not constant. However, since `file()` returns an immutable object, there's no harm in using it as a constant since it really is constant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148741/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-perl-pathclassfile-with-use-constant-gives).

Comment: There are 148 deleted comments on this answer. We're tired of dealing with this ongoing argument, so any further comments will be deleted. If you have more to say, take it to the above-linked chatroom.